# Can't mount sd card

Tags: mount, fat

I can't seem to figure how to mount an old 2GB sd card I had lying around from years ago. I forgot what I had on it...

Using Debian 11 with KDE 5.20.5

- It's not recognized or mounted when insterted (other cards are, after restarting Dolphin several times, apparently a kde bug...)
- When trying to mount manually (also tried with `-t vfat/exfat`):

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/sdcard/
  mount: /mnt/sdcard: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mmcblk0p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
  ```
- parted output:

  ```
  Warning: Unable to open /dev/mmcblk0 read-write (Read-only file system). /dev/mmcblk0 has been opened read-only.
  Model: SD 00000 (sd/mmc)                                                  
  Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 2003MB
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
  Partition Table: msdos
  Disk Flags: 

  Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
   1      66.0kB  2003MB  2003MB  primary
  ```
- made a backup with `dd`, that worked, now I have 2GB file on my hdd.
- Also tried mkfs.vfat and mkfs.exfat, both complain thye can't open since it's read-only file system
- `dmesg`

  ```
  [1238558.491514] mmc0: new high speed SD card at address 0002
  [1238558.492101] mmcblk0: mmc0:0002 00000 1.87 GiB (ro)
  [1238558.509775]  mmcblk0: p1
  [1239085.062158] exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): invalid boot record signature
  [1239085.062168] exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): failed to read boot sector
  [1239085.062172] exFAT-fs (mmcblk0p1): failed to recognize exfat type
  ```
- tried `fsck`:

  ```
  sudo fsck.fat -n /dev/mmcblk0p1
  fsck.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
  Logical sector size (7 bytes) is not a multiple of the physical sector size.
  ```

Comment: It may be there is nothing on it given that it does not have a valid file system type flagged, or perhaps it is corrupted or broken. I would `dd` to  file then run `strings` on it and check what you see.

Comment: Just tried, found `strings` in the `binutils` package in debian. Loots of strings, looks like I have an old "backup dump" of looots of files on that sd card from years ago, recognized most of the legible ones. So I guess the files must be intact, only whatever's at the start must be corrupted/malformed..

Comment: Perhaps you tarred it directly to the partition.

Comment: No idea what that means to be honest, I'm still new to linux to be honest. The best I can remember, I used to keep this sd in my phone, when I bought a bigger one, I started using this card for backups with my windows 7 laptop, then it sat in the corner of my drawer for years... No recollection if I formatted it in any way. Was just curious to learn something new by trying to troubleshoot why linux won't see it. Don't have any windows machine atm to test it there.

Comment: To create the backup, you may have run something similar to `tar cvf /dev/mmcblk0p1 /file`, that is, you created the backup directly on the partition. Try running `tar tvf /dev/mmcblk0p1` and see what returns, bit of a long shot though...

Comment: The partition on that card was created by either windows 7 or my old samsung phone (can they format?), or, most likely, as it came from the store, anywhere between 5 to 10 years ago. I didn't have a Linux machine back then, I simply copied a bunch of files from windows.